# Constructor function as an event emitter

Tags: javascript, oop, node.js, events

I would like to write a constructor function for some work I'm doing in node.js. Amongst other things, I'd like to log the number of instances it creates using an event emitter. At the moment I do this by giving the constructor object a method which is an event emitter. For example:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

function MyObject() {
    ...
    MyObject.events.emit('createdMyObject')
}

MyObject.events = new EventEmitter();

/* somewhere else... */

MyObject.events.on('createdMyObject', function () {
    // Do something when a new instance is created.
});
```

What I'd really prefer is for the constructor to more directly emit events, so I could listen for them with something like:

```
MyObject.on('createdMyObject', function () {
    // Do something when a new instance is created.
});
```

Is there a way to do this?

Please note, I don't need the instances to be event emitters (there are lots of examples of this when you google it). I want something equivalent to a *class method* in the parlance of some other OO languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solved using the non-standard (yet apparently quite commonly used) `__proto__` property of the constructor. For example:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

MyObj = function (a) {
    this.a = a;
    MyObj.emit('new')
}

MyObj.__proto__ = EventEmitter.prototype;

MyObj.on('new', function () {
    console.log('A new myObj was constructed.');
});

var myObj = new MyObj(1);
```

The expected `{ a: 1 }` object is created, and the creation event triggers the console.log! If anyone can provide an alternative route to this behaviour using something like `Object.create`, then that is certainly preferable for compliance reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just alias `events.on` to `on`? :

```
// Note: can't use simple function assignment because we need
// the "this" inside on to point to events instead of MyObject

MyObject.on = function (eventType,callback) {
    MyObject.events.on(eventType,callback);
}
```

it doesn't get rid of MyObjects.events but just provides an alternative method to add event handlers.

---

### Additional answer

If you really want your object to be an event emitter, perhaps what you want is to inherit from an EventEmitter object? If so, simply do regular inheritance:

```
function MyObject() {
    /*
     * MyObject specific stuff here
     */

    this.emit('createdMyObject');
}

// Now we inherit from an EventEmitter object:
MyObject.prototype = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype);
```

Comment: It'll work, but I'd rather the constructor was a genuine event emitter.

Comment: The second answer seems to make instances event emitters, which is not the problem. I really need the constructor to be the emitter so I have only one thing to set listeners on.

Answer (score 0):

This is example, how to construct object that is event emmiter

https://github.com/vodolaz095/kabam-kernel/blob/master/index.js#L17

```

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter,

function KabamKernel(config) {
  EventEmitter.call(this);
  //a lot of code
}
//a lot of code    
util.inherits(KabamKernel, EventEmitter);
//a lot of code

var kernel = new kabamKernel(configOj);
kernel.on('error',console.error); //kernel is an event emmiter!!!
```

```

Comment: Sorry, but this is an object. I have no issues constructing event emitter objects. I want to construct an event emitter *function* (as stated in the title).